# How can one use the latex notation in r-plot?

Tags: r, plot, latex

I want to use the latex notation to lable the axis of my plot. How is it possible?
My Code is:

```
plot(all.year, norm.aver,
     ylim=range(c(norm.aver-norm.stdv, 3.5)),
     pch=19, xlab="Year", ylab=c("GL(N) +/-",expression(sigma)),
     main=" "
)
```

I want to have;

```
ylab=GL_{S}(N)\pm \sigma
```

as a latex output for the label of y-axis.
If I use `expression(sigma)` it would work just in main however not in `ylab` !
I am grateful for every hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read `help("plotmath")`.

```
plot(1, 1, xlab="Year", ylab=expression(GL[S](N) %+-% symbol(s)))
```

[image: resulting plot]